# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity error when trying to switch between activities

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity

I am new at this and I am trying to transition from a fragment to a new activity using a button to add data into shared preferences and display it in a list view in the fragment (it's part of MainActivity). When I click on the floating button, I get the error:

{java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.calculator3dprinting/com.example.calculator3dprinting.PrinterAddActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference}

Here is the fragment and the activity I want to switch to

```
import android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.AdapterView
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.ListView
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton


class PrinterFragment: Fragment() {
    private val TAG = "PrinterFragment"
    private lateinit var pMap: PrinterManager
    private lateinit var mListView: ListView
    private lateinit var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
    //private val db = DatabaseManager()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.printer_fragment, container, false)
        mListView = view.findViewById(R.id.ListView)

        val newPrinter: FloatingActionButton = view.findViewById(R.id.addPrinter)
        newPrinter.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this.context, PrinterAddActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        //AsyncTask.execute() {
        populateListView(mListView, view)
        //}
        return view
    }

    private fun populateListView(mListView: ListView, view: View) {
        /*
        db.context = view.context
        db.initialize()

        val data = db.getPrinterNames()

        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(
            view.context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data
        )
        mListView.adapter = adapter

        mListView.onItemClickListener =
            OnItemClickListener { adapterView, _, i, _ ->
                val name = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString()
                Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: You Clicked on $name")

                val itemId = db.getPrinterIdByName(name) //get the id associated with that name

                Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: The ID is: $itemId")
                val editScreenIntent =
                    Intent(view.context, PrinterEditActivity::class.java)
                editScreenIntent.putExtra("id", itemId)
                startActivity(editScreenIntent)

            }
    }
    */
        sharedPreferences = requireContext().getSharedPreferences("Printers", MODE_PRIVATE)
        pMap = PrinterManager(sharedPreferences.all as MutableMap<Int, PrinterManager.Printers>)

        val pList = pMap.hashPrinter.values.toList()
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(view.context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pList)
        mListView.adapter = adapter

        mListView.onItemClickListener =
            AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { adapterView, _, i, _ ->
                val name = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString()
                Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: You Clicked on $name")

                val itemId = pMap.getIdByName(name) //get the id associated with that name

                Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: The ID is: $itemId")
                val editScreenIntent =
                    Intent(view.context, PrinterEditActivity::class.java)
                editScreenIntent.putExtra("id", itemId)
                startActivity(editScreenIntent)
            }
    }
}
```

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class PrinterAddActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    //private val db = DatabaseManager()
    private lateinit var pMap: PrinterManager
    private val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
            = applicationContext.getSharedPreferences("Printers", MODE_PRIVATE)
    private val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_printer_add)

        val savePrinter: Button = findViewById(R.id.save_printerBtn)
        val backButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.back_printer)

        val editName: EditText = findViewById(R.id.pAdd_name)
        val editDiam: EditText = findViewById(R.id.materialAdd_diameter)
        val editPrice: EditText = findViewById(R.id.pAdd_price)
        val editDepH: EditText = findViewById(R.id.depreciationAdd_time)
        val editSvc: EditText = findViewById(R.id.serviceAdd_costs)
        val editEnergy: EditText = findViewById(R.id.energyAdd_consumption)


        savePrinter.setOnClickListener {
            val id: Int
            val item1 = editName.text.toString()
            val item2 = editDiam.text.toString().toDouble()
            val item3 = editPrice.text.toString().toDouble()
            val item4 = editDepH.text.toString().toDouble()
            val item5 = editSvc.text.toString().toDouble()
            val item6 = editEnergy.text.toString().toDouble()

            //AsyncTask.execute() {
            if (item1 != "" || !item3.equals(null)
                || !item4.equals(null) || !item6.equals(null)
            ) {
                id = pMap.addPrinterAndGetId(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6)
                editor.putStringSet(id.toString(), pMap.toMutableString(pMap.getPrinterById(id)))
                editor.commit()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this, "Important Fields have not been filled out",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }
            //}
        }

        backButton.setOnClickListener {
            val i = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(i)
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the errors:

```
2020-12-03 21:58:27.983 20229-20229/com.example.calculator3dprinting E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.calculator3dprinting, PID: 20229
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.calculator3dprinting/com.example.calculator3dprinting.PrinterAddActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:118)
        at com.example.calculator3dprinting.PrinterAddActivity.<init>(PrinterAddActivity.kt:15)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1243)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3182)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

I appreciate any feedback you can give :)

Comment: removed `android-studio` tag. This tag is for questions/problems with Android Studio itself. Your question is not related to Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stacktrace (the error report thing) reads backwards - the top line tells you the error, and the series of calls that led to it. It's split into sections, so the second `Caused by` part tells you what caused the error above it. It's saying you tried to call:

```
android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()
```

on a null reference - i.e. you tried to call `getApplicationContext()` on something that should be a `Context` but was actually null.

A couple of lines down (stepping back through the things that caused the crash) it says you were in the initialisation block of `PrinterAddActivity`, and tells you the line number (`PrinterAddActivity.kt:15`). That's where yr problem is

---

That was just showing you how to work out where problems might be coming from! Basically your issue is you're referring to `applicationContext` (which is really `getApplicationContext()` in Kotlin) when you initialise `val sharedPreferences` - but your `Activity` doesn't have a context when you first create it. That shows up later in its lifecycle, so it's null at the point you're trying to access it.

This is probably a good candidate for a `lazy` delegate

```
private val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences by lazy { applicationContext.getSharedPreferences("Printers", MODE_PRIVATE) }
```

Same thing really, except it gets initialised lazily, when it's first accessed - ideally you'll be doing that when the `Activity` has its context, like from `onCreate` onwards! Which you're currently not - `editor` references it when *that* gets initialised. So you'll either need to wrap that in a `lazy` too, but you could just ditch it altogether and call `edit()` when you're doing an edit